# Develop PhoneGap app for old android device

Tags: android, cordova

I have a simple, but useful app for an old android device I want to develop with Cordova PhoneGap. Going through [their tutorial](https://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/build-cordova-project.html), by default, the current version of cordova requires android level 14 api to build apps, but I've done the following to get the app to build on my old 2.3.6 device...

In /config.xml add the following in the platform->android tag

```
<platform name="android">
      <allow-intent href="market:*" />
      <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
      <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="10" />
</platform
```

Edit these lines in the /platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" package="fi.blogspot.codinginthecold" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="10" tools:overrideLibrary="org.apache.cordova" />
```

Like I said, the HelloWorld app compiles on the device without error, but when I actually run the app, it says the app has unfortunately stopped.

My question: As the above method failed to run the simplest app, what is best way to develop PhoneGap apps for old android devices?

Thanks.